# Complex MySQL SELECT Query

Tags: mysql, select

Hi still getting my head around MySQL so was hoping someone may be able to shed some light on this one

I have a table named **customers** which has the following columns

```
msisdn BIGINT 20
join_date DATETIME
```

The msisdn is a unique value to identify customers.

There is a second table named **ws_billing_all** which has the following structure

```
id  INTEGER  11 (Primary Key)
msisdn BIGINT 20
event_time DATETIME
revenue INTEGER
```

So this table stores all transactions for each of the customers in the customers table as identified by the msisdn.

What I need to do is to determine the amount from all customers that joined on a particular day after 30 days.

So for example, on the 2nd of Dec 2010, 1,100 customers were acquired. Based on the data in ws_billing_all, how much total revenue did the customers that joined on this day generate 30 days from this date.

I will probably need another table for this but not sure and really not sure on how to go about extracting this data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cularis was very close... You only care about those customers that joined on the ONE DAY, and want all THEIR REVENUEs earned for the next 30 days...  In this scenario, a customer would never have sales prior to their join date, so I didn't add an explicit between on their actual sales dates of consideration.

```
SELECT 
      date( c.Join_Date ) DateJoined, 
      count( distinct c.msisdn ) DistinctMembers,
      count(*) NumberOfOrders,
      SUM(w.revenue) AmountOfRevenue
   FROM 
      customers c
         JOIN ws_billing_all w 
            ON c.msisdn = w.msisdn
           AND date( w.event_time ) <= date_add( c.Join_Date, INTERVAL 30 DAY )
   WHERE
      c.Join_Date >= SomeDateParameterValue
   group by 
      date( c.Join_Date )
   order by
      date( C.Join_Date )
```

---

### EDIT -- For clarification...

If you had 150 people join on Dec 1, 45 people on Dec 2, 83 people on Dec 3, you want to see the total revenue per group of people based on the day they joined going out 30 days of their sales...  So...

```
Joined on     Number of People     Total Revenue after 30 days
Dec 1         150                  $21,394   (up to Dec 31)
Dec 2          45                  $ 4,182   (up to Jan 1)
Dec 3          83                  $ 6,829   (up to Jan 2)
```

Does this better clarify what you want?  Then we can adjust the query...

**FINAL EDIT ...**

I think I have what you INTENDED (with a count of orders too that might be useful).  In the future, providing a sample output of something of complex nature would be helpful, even if it was as simple as I've done here.

With respect to my WHERE clause from the customers table.... Say you only cared about customers who joined within a given time frame, or only after a given date... THIS is where you would update the clause... if you want based on ALL people, then just remove it completely.

Comment: See comment above, I need the data displayed by date and then revenue and not msisdn. Also I don't want to have to specify the date, it should check for all dates, i.e any day when any customers started

Comment: @Michael Farah, see adjustment, please clarify.  You want to see daily revenues based on anyone that joined ON OR AFTER some given date, OR... Just those who joined on that one date specifically.  Is the 30 days based on when the person joined, or based on the start date you are concerned with.

Comment: Thanks, it's based on the date that the person joined. So for example I would expect to see the generated data looking something like this

Comment: Where the date is shown and the amount of revenue generated after 30 days

Comment: However, the query should check for all dates in which customers joined and return a row for each date

Comment: Still a bit confused, what do I use for SomeDateParameterValue in the AND statement?

Comment: OK, I've adjusted the query as follows

Comment: SELECT 
      date( w.event_time ) as DateOfRevenue, 
      SUM(w.revenue) AmountOfRevenue
   FROM 
      analysis_customers c
         JOIN ws_billing_all w 
            ON c.msisdn = w.msisdn
              group by 
      date( w.event_time )
   order by
      date( w.event_time )

Comment: This gives me close to what I need, it shows all the revenue generated from customers that joined on that date. Now I need to just ensure only revenue after the first 30 days is shown

Comment: Yes exactly! That's it in a nutshell!

Comment: @Michael Farah, finished... review again

Comment: Hi, the revenue column is calculating correctly so thanks for that. However the distinct msisdn column does not produce the correct value. Not sure why

Comment: @DRapp let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1886/discussion-between-michael-farah-and-drapp)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.msisdn, SUM(w.revenue)
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN ws_billing_all w ON c.msisdn=w.msisdn
WHERE w.event_time BETWEEN c.join_date AND DATE_ADD(c.join_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY c.msisdn
```

You have to join both tables on the customer id. Then select all events that happened between the join date and 30 days after that. Group by the customer id and use SUM() to get total revenue per costumer.

Comment: Thanks, will try it now. One thing, don't I need to use something like DATE to determine all revenue from that day as opposed to a specific time in the day?

Comment: I don't think I understand you completely, but BETWEEN ... AND ... checks if the event was between the join date and 30 days later.

Comment: The thing is I want to group by day and not customer. I'm interested in how much revenue the entire group of customers that joined on a particular day generated after 30 days.